# Can I install the preinstalled Mac OS X Mountain Lion on other Macs?

Tags: macos

I just ordered a Mac that will be shipped with Mountain Lion. Is it possible to install Mountain Lion on my other Macs? Or do I have to buy an upgrade in the App Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The preinstalled copy of Mountain Lion is not licensed to be installed on additional machines.

From the [Software License Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX108.pdf) (2.A.):

> Preinstalled and Single-Copy Apple Software License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, unless you obtained the Apple Software from the Mac App Store or under a volume license, maintenance or other written agreement from Apple, you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and **run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple-branded computer at any one time**. For example, these single-copy license terms apply to you if you obtained the Apple Software 
>   ￼￼￼preinstalled on Apple-branded hardware.

*(emphasis added)*

You will have to buy an upgrade in the App Store for your other Macs, however for non-commercial use you can install a single App Store purchase on multiple machines, given all the computers are in your control.