# Upgrading a Mac from Leopard to Lion

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, upgrade

I've two Macs: one MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo with 10.5.8 (Leopard) and the other MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo with 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

How can I upgrade the Leopard Mac to Mountain Lion while leaving the Snow Leopard Mac as it is for now.

Comment: Related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51655/will-i-still-be-able-to-buy-and-install-lion-after-mountain-lion-is-released

Comment: @lhf Also not relevant - this is talking about buying Mountain Lion, not Lion. Presumably the OP either a) knows they can't buy Lion, b) wants Mountain Lion and so hasn't thought about it and doesn't care, or c) has already read about it and resigned themselves to paying less for a newer OS.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you need is in [this Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/how-to-create-a-bootable-backup-mountain-lion-install-disk/).

Essentially:

1. Purchase and download Mountain Lion on your 10.6 Snow Leopard Mac.
2. Follow the instructions from the article (or elsewhere here on Ask Different) to make the bootable disk.
3. Put the disk into your Leopard Mac and upgrade! (You may have to do a clean install.)

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/can-i-install-the-preinstalled-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-on-other-macs for different take.

Comment: @lhf That's not relevant - that's installing a copy of Mountain Lion that was pre-installed on a Mac on a different Mac so you have two installed copies using one license. Here, we're *purchasing* a license on one Mac but *using* it on a different Mac - we're not using more copies than we're allowed to.